# Structure and arrange emitted particles

Tags: particles

1: Is there a way to emit particles in a linear and structured order like shown in the picture?

2: Even better: Is there a way to animate the particles from random to a structured order seamlessly?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend to use geometry nodes for that task. Then you have much more control and flexibility.

Here is an example for this:

Node tree:

[image]

3D Grid:

[image]

[image]

you get the animation just by changing/keyframing the factor of the attribute mix node.

Answer (score 0):

Add a particle system to your object, emitting from *Volume*, rather than faces.

Under distribution change from *Jittered* to *Grid*.
You can then animate the *Random* parameter to have it go from unordered distribution to an orthogonal grid.

[image]